# Looking for a preinstalled Windows COM server to test my client framework

Tags: windows, unit-testing, com

I'm writing a framework for COM clients in Windows and would like to test it against some preinstalled COM servers. Are there some well known servers I could use to run my unit tests?

Comment: [Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773938(v=vs.85).aspx) objects?

Comment: [WindowsInstaller.Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([since Win2k SP3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371185%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that for yourself in the registry at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID.  Some of the first ones are part of the core of COM, e.g. {0000031A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}, the class moniker.

You can also use OleView.exe, it comes with the Windows SDK and Visual Studio (at least the flavors with C++), and check out under Object Classes > All Objects.  Copy this tool into a clean Windows installation and check the stock objects.

However, avoid the PSFactoryBuffere (PS* in general), as they are proxy-stub marshalers and some are probably free-threaded marshaled themselves.

What might be interesting are the interfaces accessible from those objects, so you'll want to look for stock type libraries in OleView.exe.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, should I conclude that there is no (well known) COM server whose primary goal is to offer clients with testing features? That would be useful, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not really, such object would be either too simple or too complex for most testing purposes.  Why don't you make your own test objects?

Comment: I will. Thanks for the insights.